# .htaccess mod_rewrite won't skip RewriteRule with [S]

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, skip

As an FYI, I am using the following .htaccess file in located at `www.site.com/content/`

When a user visits www.site.com/content/**login** I want it to display the content from www.site.com/content/**userlogin.php** (masked via rewrite, and not redirect) - which I have done SUCCESSFULLY like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /content/
RewriteRule ^login/?$ /content/userlogin.php [NC,L]
```

However, I would like to add the follwoing: If they try to access www.site.com/content/**userlogin.php** directly, I want them to get redirected to a 404 page at www.site.com/content/**error/404.php**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /content/
RewriteRule ^login/?$ /content/userlogin.php [NC,S=1,L]
RewriteRule ^userlogin\.php$ /content/error/404.php [NC,L]
```

With that in the .htaccess file, both www.site.com/content/**login** and www.site.com/content/**userlogin.php** show www.site.com/content/**error/404.php**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the S=1 will have no function as the L directive will make any further rewriting stop.
It seems like the first RewriteRule makes Apache go through the .htaccess rules one more time, so you need to know if the first rewrite has happend. You could do this by setting an environment variable like this:

```
RewriteRule ^login/?$ /content/userlogin.php [E=DONE:true,NC,L]
```

So when the next redirect occurs the Environment variable actually gets rewritten to `REDIRECT_<variable>` and you can do a RewriteCond on this one like this:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_DONE} !true
RewriteRule ^userlogin\.php$ /content/error/404.php [NC,L]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This works exactly like you wrote it, thank you. I've encountered a new set of problems based on my specific application however, so I will try to figure it out before I admit defeat. Cheers! (from a guy named Bjorn)

Answer (score 0):

Use `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable in your code instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /content/

RewriteRule ^login/?$ content/userlogin.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+userlogin\.php[\s\?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ content/error/404.php [L]
```